# CodeIgniter routing issues with subdirectories

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

I am working on a web app that is located in a child folder of a folder in my htdocs.  Like this:

```
http://localhost/folder/another_folder/index.php
```

I can force routing to my controllers by getting:

```
http://localhost/folder/another_folder/index.php/controller
```

But I cannot get my routes to behave as expected:

```
$route['auth/login/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'auth/login/$1/$2';
```

I also tried:

```
$route['auth/login/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'folder/another_folder/auth/login/$1/$2';
$route['another_folder/login(:any)/(:any)'] = 'auth/login/$1/$2';
```

And various other permutations.  In all cases I get CI 404s or standard 404s.  I need a solution that is portable, so when I publish this in the test server where it'll be at on level of subdirectory, and when I publish to production where it'll be root I only need to change one (or fewer!) lines of code.  Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

Configuring base_url in config.php seems to be the trick for this!